# How to get all form data entries from request in a spring controller

Tags: spring-boot, request

Is there any way to get all form data entries described below in `spring controller`?
I tried several ways like `Multipartfile[]`, `HttpServletRequest` as controller parameters

```
public ResponseEntity<String> endpoint1(HttpServletRequest request)
```

but it seems that spring somehow validates the form data and rejects all form data entries that have file or files as value and their key is other than "file" or "files" so the "file1" and "file2" are not presented in any field of `HttpServletRequest  request`

the other form data entries `data data2 data3` are presented in

```
HttpServletRequest request getParameterMap
```

[image: Postman request form data]

Answer (score 1):

```
@PutMapping(value="/api/event/videos/update/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, 
    @RequestParam("file1") MultipartFile file1, @RequestParam("file2") MultipartFile file2, 
    @RequestParam("data") Object data, @RequestParam("data1") Object data1, 
    @RequestParam("data2") Object data2) {
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       DataResource dataResource = mapper.readValue(object.toString(), DataResource.class);
       Data1Resource data1Resource = mapper.readValue(object.toString(), Data1Resource.class);
       Data2Resource data2Resource = mapper.readValue(object.toString(), Data2Resource.class);
       return ......
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the number of the form data entries is not static can be dynamic and I want a generic structure like a map that contains them all

Comment: There are some other options available `@RequestParam Map<String, Data> parameters` or `@RequestParam(value = "Datas") Set<Data> test`  or `@MatrixVariable`